# Is android SQ LITE file will be accessible to another user

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am a new bee in android platform and creating an application.I Need to save few data in to database and shared between two application.The data I am using for licensing, so my question is Is it possible to others to copy my data base from 'data/data/pack_name/database_name' and put it into a new device?. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the licensing you are talking about?

Comment: That is different. My question is,is it possible to others to copy my data base?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible for application B to copy application A data without explicit permission of application B. We have content providers specifically for the purpose of sharing data between application. But you can always try this out by creating and application and trying to access it's data from another application.

Answer (score 0):

If the device is rooted then I believe it is possible for another application to copy your data.